# Flipping part of a multidimensional-array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

My goal with this function was to make it so that the rows of this array flip. Essentially, row 0 is now the last row, row 1 is now the next to last row and so on. Any ideas why I'm getting a segmentation fault or if there is a better way to do this? Thanks, here's the code for the function:

```
ppmPic *flipVertical(ppmPic *pOriginal) {
    ppmPic *newPic = malloc(sizeof(ppmPic));
    newPic = pOriginal;
    for(int a=0; a<newPic->rows; a++) {
            for(int b=0; b<newPic->cols; b++) {
                    newPic->pixels[a][b].red = newPic->pixels[newPic->rows - a][b].red;
                    newPic->pixels[a][b].green = newPic->pixels[newPic->rows - a][b].green;
                    newPic->pixels[a][b].blue = newPic->pixels[newPic->rows - a][b].blue;
            }
    }

    return newPic;
}
```

Comment: Post an [mcve]. try `newPic->rows - a -1` same for two other case. Your code don't make any sense `newPic = pOriginal;` ???

Comment: 1. `ppmPic *newPic = malloc(sizeof(ppmPic));` 2. `newPic = pOriginal;` Immediately, after having `malloc`ed memory for the new picture you override the resp. pointer `newPic`. So, you have now a memory leak and start overriding memory provided by `pOriginal`.

Comment: `ppmPic *newPic = malloc(sizeof(ppmPic));` directly followed by `newPic = pOriginal;` is a memory leak. And will not do what you probably think it does (copy `pOriginal`).

Comment: Remove  `newPic = pOriginal;` and replace `newPic->pixels[newPic->rows - a][b].red;` --> `pOriginal->pixels[pOriginal->rows - a][b].red;` and repeat same to other lines as well

Comment: Show the declaration of `ppmPic`.

Comment: All C compilers (even most of those produced in the decade before the original C standard — that is, during the 1980s) could handle structure assignments; you don't need to assign the coloured elements separately.

Comment: I think it likely that you need to allocate space to hold the pixels based on the size of the image (the rows and columns).  You need to set the sizes in the new image before you use the sizes.  This isn't clear since you've not shown the structure you are working with.

Comment: Normally you should present code that compiles if we copy and paste it. You are missing so many declarations, that it is hard to see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious issue with your code are the copy lines:

```
newPic->pixels[a][b].red = newPic->pixels[newPic->rows - a][b].red;
```

Recognize that the value ranges for a row are from [0 .. rows-1].  Your first assignment will reference `pixels[rows]` which is an off by 1 error.  You're referencing an index into the array that is not valid.

And you likely meant to be copying from the source image. So you really meant to be saying this most likely:

```
newPic->pixels[a][b].red = pOriginal->pixels[pOriginal->rows - a][b].red;
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that your definition of ppmPic references the same thing [this site](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/write-c-program-read-write-copy-grow-shrink-ppm-file-manipulating-ppm-file-basically-typed-q12467339) is referring to.

In which case, a ppmPic is definied as follows:

```
typedef struct ppm {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int colors;
    Pixel **pixels;
} ppmPic;

typedef struct pixel {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
} Pixel;
```

And if my assumption is that the `pixels` member of a ppmPic in an array of rows (which each row is an allocation of column cells), then the following will flip your image.  We'll use `memcpy` to do the heavy lifting of copying an entire row.

```
ppmPic* flipVertical(ppmPic *pOriginal)
{
    ppmPic* newPic = malloc(sizeof(ppmPic));
    int rows = pOriginal->rows;
    int cols = pOriginal->cols;

    // allocate an array of "rows"
    Pixel** pixels = (Pixel**)malloc(rows * sizeof(Pixel*));

    // now allocate each row, and copy from the original into it    
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        pixels[r] = (Pixel*)malloc(cols * sizeof(Pixel));
        mempcy(pixels[r], pOriginal->pixels[rows-r-1], cols * sizeof(Pixel));
    }

    newPic.rows = rows;
    newPic.cols = cols;
    newPic.pixels = pixels;
    newPic.colors = pOriginal->colors; // honestly, I'm not sure if colors is revelant here.. and if it is, that may mean that our allocation for each row needs to change
    return newPic;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an implicit declaration of memcpy even though I have #include <string.h>

Comment: Nevermind, I had spelled it wrong and now it works! Thank you